# Customize TOC using KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I want to customize my ToC and read that the package `tocloft` is not the good package to use in combination with the KOMA-Script. With the package `tocstyle` I also get warnings about version conflicts.

Since I think my adjustment are not to complicated maybe it is also possible to do them without such a package, however I have no clue how to do that.

- I want to have the same format for my ToC as the chapter,section and subsection styles. So the number in the left margin and the names in the body at the right side aligned. (See MWE and image)

Does someone have any idea?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
includemp,
                  showframe,
                  reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,
            inner=2.7cm,
            outer=2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ 
}\thechapter\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}

% remove the vertical skip before the chapter heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}

\usepackage[footwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark{chapter}
\ifoot{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}%
  \ifodd \value{page}%
    Quantifying goodness of morphodynamic field predictions
  \else
    \headmark %
  \fi
}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do almost the same for the entries to the table of contents as for the headings:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
  includemp,
  showframe,
  reversemp,
  paperwidth=20.1cm,
  paperheight=25.80cm,
  top=2.30cm,
  bottom=3.4cm,
  inner=2.7cm,
  outer=2.7cm,
  marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
  marginparsep=0.4cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\intoleftmargin{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ 
}\thechapter\autodot}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\intoleftmargin{\thesection\autodot}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\intoleftmargin{\thesubsection\autodot}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\intoleftmargin{\thesubsubsection\autodot}}

% remove the vertical skip before the chapter heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocnumwidth=0pt,tocindent=0pt,tocentrynumberformat=\intoleftmargin]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
\newcommand*{\intoleftmargin}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1\hskip\marginparsep}}

\usepackage[footwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark{chapter}
\ifoot{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}%
  \ifodd \value{page}%
    Quantifying goodness of morphodynamic field predictions
  \else
    \headmark %
  \fi
}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

For more information about [`\RedeclareSectionCommand`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls-experts.cmd.ProvideSectionCommand) and options like `tocnumwidth`, `tocindent` and `tocentrynumberformat` (which are the options `numwidth`, `indent` and `entrynumberformat` of style `tocline` of command [`\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:tocbasic.cmd.DeclareTOCStyleEntry)) see [the English KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) or [the German KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf) or even [the German KOMA-Script book](https://www.komascript.de/komascriptbuch).

[image: ToC and one more page]

Comment: Excuse me for the bad formatting in the question. Many thanks!